# Get number of active users for an iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics, google-fabric

We are building a custom, company-wide dashboard. Is there a way to get the number of users (through REST API) that downloaded and are actively using our iOS App?

Our app has Fabric integration (seems Fabric will be a part of Firebase soon?), but maybe there are other, better alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

I checked Fabric and Firebase's document, there is no REST API to get activity data from these service. You can get data from their dashboard, the format is csv.
I saw some python library claimed they can do this job, but not sure these library can work or not. You can search "Firebase or Fabric" on PyPi.